# How to fix not getting text response from Post request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest

I'm new to using nodejs and javascript so I'm sorry if I'm just doing something obviously wrong. I have a nodejs app I'm running and serves a html page. That html page can send Post requests using XMLHttpRequest. The request goes though and my node app calls the function that my request is meant to invoke. The problem is I want to get some data back from that request so I am trying to get that from the response to the request. The issue is I am getting an empty response and I do not know why.

Here is my request.

```
function SendCachedTriangulation(){
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('responseLog').textContent = "sent triangulation: " + this.response;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("Post", "/sendCachedTriangulation");
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            var text = '{ "data" : ' + '{ "someData":"' + '1' + '" } }';

            xhttp.send(text);
            return false;
```

}

The result I get from this is response is empty. It does update the element I am trying to update but it just says "sent triangulation: ".

On the nodejs side this is my code.

```
router.post('/sendCachedTriangulation', (req, res, next) => {
client.SendCachedTriangulation(() => {    
        res.status(200)
    ;}, req.body
    );       
res.status(200).message = "sent triangulation";
res.send();
```

});

Which this seems to be calling my function to send cached triangulation properly i just don't get that "sent triangulation" message.

What do I need to change to display that message in my HTML page?

Comment: Are you making an request inside you router? Don't know if it will solve your problem, but first you need to understand the separation between server and client. Seems your router is an express router, so its only responds to client request. this request must to be outside the router, actually, it may be from other place, like an HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new to the whole server and client thing so I'll do my best to explain what I have done here. The first code block that makes the request in my html page that gets served by my nodejs app. The second code block is from the routes I have setup in my nodejs app. So what I'm trying to do is make the html page make requests to the nodejs app and get a response on what happened. I hope I understood your question well enough to answer it. Please let me know if I need to restructure how I'm doing this or something.

Comment: One other thing to note. I am getting this error when I make this command in the console of the html page.

XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:3001/sendCachedTriangulation
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: Actually I understood your snippet. I also understand that is complicated at first time with Node, because is everything Javascript. Let me explain: in your HTML, think the request is OK, but actually have, let's say, two files: HTML file, that performs the request, and the node HTTP server, that responds the request. So I mean something like:

// /server/app.js
router.post('/sendCachedTriagulation', (req, res, next) => {
     res.status(200).send("sent triangulation")
})

// /client/index.html

client.SendCachedTriangulation() //...

Comment: Wahoo! that worked!!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: how do I make your comment the chosen answer on here? sorry, I'm new on here as well lol

Comment: Actually I don't know, I didn't respond the question in the answer area. Will make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I understood your snippet. I also understand that is complicated at first time with Node, because is everything Javascript. Let me explain: in your HTML, think the request is OK, but actually have, let's say, two files: HTML file, that performs the request, and the node HTTP server, that responds the request. So I mean something like:

```
// /server/app.js 

router.post('/sendCachedTriagulation', (req, res, next) => { 
      res.status(200).send("sent triangulation") 
}) 

// /client/index.html 

client.SendCachedTriangulation(/* do stuff */)
```